# any way to obtain the "dot git" (.git) directory from a github repository?

Tags: git, github, config

### Background

- github (version as of 2014-10-27)
- creating a new repository on github using the github web interface

### Problem

#### Goal

- Goal: to get a copy of the .git directory that git creates when "git init" is run

#### Details

Trevor has created a repository on github by using the following link:

- https://github.com/new

Trevor would like to obtain the .git directory that was created on github's server, in order
to compare some aspects of it with the .git directory that was created on his local machine
when he cloned the repository there.

#### Failed attempts

- Trevor has not attempted to do this yet, because there does not appear to be any documentation covering how to get this done.

### See also

Web links:

- https://help.github.com/
- https://github.com/new

### Questions

- Is there any way to do this, or is Trevor out of luck?
- If there is no way to do this, is there any way to learn the details of what github puts into its own .git directories when a new repo is created through the github web interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very specific question about githubs internal structure. You really should contact support@github.com with these questions, because they will be able to give you a much better answer.

However, as far as I know, you can't get the exact .git-directory from github and even if you could it would probably be useless to you since it will contain github-specific information.

I'm still puzzled about why you want to know this. I can't see any reason for this since git is distributed. What information are you looking for in the .git-repository on github?

What aspects do you want to compare?

The reason that I ask is that I believe you're trying to solve a problem the wrong way. As explained in the famous "how to ask questions the smart way":
http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal

Comment: **//I'm still puzzled about why you want to know this.//** because Trevor knows he will learn things by looking at the internals that he would not be able to learn by any other means. 

Ironically, the question here does **exactly** what is referenced in the famous document just cited: **Describe the goal, not the step** ... the goal is specified under "goal" in the SO question. The goal is to look at the .git directory generated by github, **specifically for the purpose of exploration**.

Comment: Feel free to think of it as a quest for **the serendipity of fortuitous discovery**. Generally speaking, one of the best ways of learning the internals of any tool or system is to (perhaps not surprisingly) directly examine the internals of the tool or system.

Thanks much for your reply and for your encouragement to focus on the goal. If you have an alternate means for directly reaching the goal specified above, any input greatly appreciated.

Thanks again for your reply and for the interaction.

Comment: The problem here is that you're trying to figure out how a closed source system work. This could be viewed to be against the TOS of github that states that you're not allowed to duplicate or reproduce any part of the services ( https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/ ). I suggest that you instead look at some open source tool like gitolite or gitlab if you want to understand how git hosting can be done.

Comment: **//This could be viewed to be against the TOS of github //** No one said anything about duplicating github or misappropriating their intellectual property. 

Thank you for airing that concern. It is good to dispense with it, to avoid potential (and serious) misconception. 

The only interest is to learn more about the internals of git and clever things that people do to enhance it, both of which would certainly be obtainable by the goal specified above. If it is off-limits, and there is no legitimate way to do it, that's fine.

**There is nothing wrong with a simple and elegant "No."**